# how to improve regex to capture last n words ... too many steps

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to capture between 1 and 3 last words but it takes over 2000 steps, what am I doing wrong?

`((?:\S+\s*){1,3})$`

if I do

`.*(^|\s+)((?:\S+\s*){1,3})$`

then I only get the last word and I'm looking for between 1 and 3 words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is not optimal due to the `\s*` subpattern. When your pattern is parsed by the regex engine, it will look like `\S+\s*\S+\s*\S+$`, and since the `*` is not possessive (or no atomic group is defined here), backtracking will fall through these `\s*`.

You might use an atomic group ([`((?>\S+\s*){1,3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/0BEkC2/1)) or, best, make the pattern *linear*:

```
\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YXC0P3/1)

**Details**:

- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace symbols
- `(?:\s+\S+){0,2}` - 0 to 2 sequences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Since the `\s+` requires at least 1 symbol to match, the number of possible ways to match a string will be considerably fewer than with `\s*`.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I'm confused why its {0,2} and not {1,3}

Comment: See, `\S+` at the start matches 1+ symbols other than whitespaces. So, it is 1 word already. Thus, you only need 0, 1 or 2 more non-whitespace chunks that are separated with 1+ whitespace chunks. Hence, `{0,2}` limiting quantifier is required.